# Spring Boot GET Request gives 200 OK status, but Postman returns "[]" as response body

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

[It gives output when I PUT Request Params and Request Headers But When I change RequestBody in controller Its not showing the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYmQb.png)

CONTROLLER CLASS

```
@PostMapping("/timesheet/search")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity <List<Timesheet>>searchTimesheet(@RequestBody String query) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.searchTimesheet(query));
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the service does?

Comment: i dont know jack about spring boot ... but 200K with "[]" response is not an error in the REST world. it usually implies that the request is correct -- it fulfilled the round trip to persistent store -- but there is simply no data in the specified collection MATCHING THE QUERY. an empty array is possible.

Comment: @ABoston has right. If `service.searchTimesheet(query)` returns empty list, then your response code will be 200 and body `[]`.

Comment: Just on first glance everything appears to be correct.  Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the return method and verifying that `servicee.searchTimesheet(query)` is returning something?  is it empty?

Comment: I would say to look at your repo query/service methods to ensure that it is functioning properly. Are you using proper methodnames in the JpaRepository?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X  yes its working correctly.when I given RequestParams and RequestHeaders in  Controller class in the place of Request Body it showing the result in Resoponse body but when I place RequestBody Its not showing the output

Comment: @tbatch when I given RequestParams and RequestHeaders in Controller class in the place of Request Body it showing the result in Resoponse body but when I place RequestBody Its not showing the output

Answer (score 0):

in return statement use this beacause you are not returning the body of query object there thats why you are getting empty list there

```
 return ResponseEntity.ok().body(service.searchTimesheet(query));
```